# no envia correo phpmailer cuando uso ajax con valores javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, phpmailer

Mi emisor donde genero los datos que voy a usar para la edicion

```
function edit(event){
                start = event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                if(event.end){
                    end = event.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                }else{
                    end = start;
                }

                id =  event.id;
                titulo = event.title;
                Event = [];
                Event[0] = id;
                Event[1] = start;
                Event[2] = end;
                Event[3] = titulo;


                $.ajax({
                 url: 'editEventDate.php',
                 type: "POST",
                 data: {Event:Event},
                 success: function(rep) {
                        if(rep == 'OK'){

    swal({
      position: 'top-end',
      type: 'success',
      title: 'modificado correctamente',
      showConfirmButton: false,
      timer: 1500
    });


                        }
```

fin

Mi receptor donde incluyo el la libreria phpmailer y compruebo que los datos no esten vacios

comprobé que se hace el update de mi base de datos pero el correo no se envia...
puedo usar la libreria en cualquier otra parte de mi sistema pero en la consulta ajax no.

```
<?
    require_once('clases/bdd.php');

    require ("scripts/scriptValidaSession.php");
    require ("clases/ticket.class.php");
    require ("clases/baseDatos.class.php");
    require ("clases/usuario.class.php");
    require ("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");

    $conexion = new baseDatos();

    if ($conexion->connect_errno) {

        echo "Fallo la conexion: ".$conexion->connect_error;
    }

    $usuario = new Usuario();

    $consulta = $usuario->searchUser($conexion, $_SESSION['ticket_id']);

    $resultado = $consulta->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $ticket = new Ticket();

    $ticket->setIdUsuario($_SESSION['ticket_id']);


    if (isset($_POST['Event'][0]) && isset($_POST['Event'][1]) && isset($_POST['Event'][2]) && isset($_POST['Event'][3])){


        $id = $_POST['Event'][0];
        $start = $_POST['Event'][1];
        $end = $_POST['Event'][2];
        $titulo = $_POST['Event'][3];



        $sql = "UPDATE events SET  start = '$start', end = '$end' WHERE id = $id ";


        $query = $bdd->prepare( $sql );
        if ($query == false) {
         print_r($bdd->errorInfo());
         die ('Erreur prepare');
        }
        $sth = $query->execute();
        if ($sth == false) {
         print_r($query->errorInfo());
         die ('Erreur execute');
        }else{
            die ('OK');
        }

    $mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //ultima 
    $mail->Port = 587;// or 465
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = "@gmail.com"; //ultima
    $mail->Password = ".";    //ultima
    $mail->SetFrom("@gmail.com","Sistemas"); //ultima 
    $mail->Subject = "Atencion! se ha modificado la hora del evento: ".$_POST['title'];
    $mail->Body = "

        <div style=\"width: 800px;height: ".(350+(strlen($_POST['observacion'])/6))."px;border: 1px solid #ddd;border-radius:6px;\">

      <div style=\"width: 770px;height: 20px;margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 20px; color: inherit;color: #333;
      background-color: #f5f5f5;
      border-color: #ddd;padding: 10px 15px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
      border-top-left-radius: 3px;
      border-top-right-radius: 3px;\">

            <strong>Evento modificado</strong>

      </div>

      <div style=\"border-top: 1px solid #ddd;padding: 15px;background:white;\">  

          Hola equipo, soy <strong>".$resultado['personaNombre']." ".$resultado['apellido']."</strong>,<br> Les informo sobre un cambio en la hora del evento , aqui la info:

          <table style=\"border-collapse: collapse;width: 100%;margin-bottom: 20px;\"> 


              <tr>
              <th style=\"background-color: #fff;text-align: left;padding-top:5px;\">Hora del evento</th>
              <td style=\"background-color: #fff;text-align: left;padding-top:5px;\">".$_POST['hora']."</td>
            </tr>

          </table>
           Muchas gracias por su apoyo :)
      </div>

    </div>";


    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->AddAddress("@gmail.com");// es la direccion de correo a donde enviamos una copia de lo ocurrido
    $mail->Send();

    }
    //header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

    ?>
```

Comment: solo por probar, puse el envio antes de el update y funciono el envio...

Comment: En tu parte del `UPDATE` estás usando métodos propios de `PDO`, como por ejemplo: `print_r($bdd->errorInfo());` y más arriba parece que usas `mysqli`, por ejemplo aquí: `$resultado = $consulta->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);`, además, en la parte del UPDATE la conexión se llama `$bdd` y en la parte de arriba se llama `$conexion` ... ¿Por qué esa diferencia y esa mezcla de métodos?